# XAP file in Windows Device 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, xap

I am new in this environment, so I do not know about this issue.
Can I get XAP file in Windows Phone 8.1? I have tried by copy-paste of "XAP" file but when I see in my phone, I can't get it.
Is it possible?If yes, then how to get it?
Thanks!!

Comment: There is no File Explorer in Windows Phone 8.1, so you won't be able to browse the XAP file. Where did you try to "see" the xap file after copying it to the phone?

Comment: @bit ohh yes, thank you so much!!so is this a limitation, right?

Comment: Yes it is a limitation. However if you want to deploy a xap of your app for testing, it can be done using the windows phone SDK